# Django admin: place inlines on the side

Tags: django, django-admin, page-layout, django-grappelli

In Django admin (possibly powered by django-grappelli), is there a way to place inlines on the right on the main form, instead of below?

I would like to have the page split into two column: the main form on the left and the related items (inlines) on the right.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need to overwrite the admin templates:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/#customize-the-admin-look-and-feel